# set $PATH as all possible paths from $HOME

Tags: linux, shell, path, repo, home-directory

Reset the path as all possible paths from `~`.
Ex:

```
$HOME$
|    \
|   stuff
repos  |  \
|   |  |   \
math|  |   random
    |  science  
   awesome   
    |    |
  cool  extra
```

$PATH$ = `~/repos:~/repos/math:~/repos/awesome:~/repos/awesome/cool:~repos/awesome/extra:~/stuff:~/stuff/science:~/stuff/random` 
Other Notes:

- The program can be in `bash`, `shell` or `python3`
- The program needs to be reuseable
- Does not involve `sudo` or root access

Comment: Isn't it better to make symlinks to your `~/bin` and keep the PATH short?

Comment: I have only changed my `.profile`. If you have another suggestion, please tell it:)

Comment: You have "installed" binaries in many different places in your `$HOME` directory? Why are they all over the place?

Answer (score 1):

Could you sort them and re-apply them to your PATH that way you won't have everything everywhere and probably avoid duplicates by running uniq after sort.

```
IFS=':' read -r -a path_arr <<< "$PATH"
for elem in `sort <<< ${path_arr[@]} | uniq`; 
do 
sorted_path+=$elem; sorted_path+=":"; 
done
PATH=$sorted_path
```